# Is the word, "problem," new to non-English languages?

Tags: language-families, borrowing

I've been listening to radio broadcasts lately where a person will be speaking German or Pashtun or Russian or whatever and a translator will be supplying an English rendition, in a format which makes it possible to hear both the original and the translation.

I noticed that in almost every case, where the interpreter says something like, "The problem is," or, "the difficulty is," the speaker in the (to me) foreign language will also say the word, "problem," identical to English and in the correct place, but merely accented in that language.

And it got me to wondering: Is "problem" a modern word or a very old indo-european word? What is its etymology and history? Does it represent a concept which was foreign to non-European cultures before the modern era, or is the speaker making word choices to accommodate an interpreter?

Comment: many languages have separate words translatable as "matter" and "grievance", but it is usually a bad translation to say the word translatable as "grievance" in the context you describe, where English _problem_ is used where _matter_ is meant.

Comment: There is more occurring than you are probably aware of. The phenomenon it seems you are observing Is very common among highly educated individuals, particularly if they have been trained in English speaking countries. Moreover, they may just be repeating words that they heard the interviewer ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you assume the word "problem" comes from English, you have an incorrect starting point.

"Problem" (note: in English) comes from late Middle English <- Old French **probleme** <- via Latin from Greek **πρόβλημα** (problēma); the word comes from **proballein** ‘put forth,’ which is **pro** ‘before’ + **ballein** ‘to throw.’ <sup>**1**</sup>

I'd say that shows that the spread didn't come from English at all. Rather, it started from Greek, took by Latin and from there to the Romances languages (and from there English). I'm not sure where Russian took it from, but considering the Russian alphabet is based on the Greek one, I don't think it would be absurd to assume that it might have come from there, although this last sentence is speculation and as such it should be considered.

So the words are not merely "accented", they actually exist in those languages:

- French, *problème*
- Italian, *problema*
- Russian, *проблема*
- Spanish, *problema*

Also, I don't think this word represents a "new concept". If you say that it's meaning or that the way it's interpreted has changed over time, then yes, *that* would be reasonable.

---

<sup>**1**: Taken from the New Oxford American Dictionary</sup>

Comment: Italian "problema" (14th century - OED), Spanish "problema" (1414, OED), Russian "проблема" (early 18th, from Polish or German, Vasmer), German "Problem" (from English).

Comment: I think I've made no such assumption; it wouldn't be at all accurate to conclude that from my question. Rather, I've been hearing it in interviews with Afghans and Africans. I don't think of "problem" as a word found in Urdu or Gujarat or Arabic, but there they were saying it. 

Bearing that in mind, though, thank you for the etymology back to the Greek. That suggests that in those non-European languages the word was introduced by modern era influences. Not correct?

Comment: @RobPerkins I've obviously based my answer on your actual question, where you made no mention of Urdu, Gujarat or Arabic. If you want to introduce these languages in your query, then yes, I think it's not wrong to think that they were influenced by English or by other languages that have the "same" word, although this would need some research as a confirmation. But considering the spread of English, it'd be fairly safe to assume so.

Comment: @AlexB. Do you happen to have a Russian etymological dictionary? By the way, doesn't that confirm the "path" I showed in the answer (apart from German which I didn't mention)? And also, although your comment was kind of cryptic, I think you were hinting that the Russian word came from the other languages, is that correct?

Comment: @Alenanno, yes. Should I edit the question for better clarity, do you think?

Comment: @RobPerkins That depends. If you want that part to be included in my answer, I can include it (in this case, yes, you should edit). If it was a side-question, then you can leave it in the comments. :)

Comment: I made an edit to your first sentence which aligns it with our discussion here in the comments.

Comment: It is Gujarati and not Gujarat. Gujarat is name of the state while Gujarati is name of the language among other things.

Comment: Hebrew: בעיה (etymologically unrelated)

Comment: [Wiktionary says](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) that Russian проблема is borrowed from Latin problema.

Comment: *Problem* likely was calqued into German as *Vorwurf*, literally "onto" + "throw", now meaning ca "afront, incrimination", otherwise completely transparent as a verb, *den Hunden zum Fraß vorwerfen* (to throw before the dogs to devour; figuratively to sacrifice, not quite perls before swine, which in that sense is closer to *ver-werfen* "to dismis, reject [an idea, appeal, etc]"). I mean, this supports the notion that "problem" did likely not exist as an alternative for translation, yet. It also suggest with some probability that it's from lithurgy (or law, which was eventually indistinct).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum same difference. I wonderedbefore how to treat cases where a word comes from language A through B to C but with the knowledge that B got it from. And not to forget loans from A through B1 and B2. For simplicities sake, A is the loaning language, and B just reinforcing a feedback loop.

Comment: @vectory, yes it came **through** Latin from Greek. My only point—not made clearly—was that it **didn't** come from English. In other words corroborating your explanation.

Comment: @AlexB. The German "Problem" is from Latin, not English, according to Pfeifer https://www.dwds.de/wb/Problem.